# Функция passwd Linux CentOS не работает

Tags: linux, centos

Не могу изменить пароль пользователя:

```
# passwd webmaster
Changing password for user webmaster.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
И функция pwconv отвечает так:
pwconv: /etc/passwd: Permission denied
pwconv: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

Не помогло:

1) Права доступа:

```
chmod 0640 /etc/shadow
```

2) Файловая система только для чтения:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: на `/etc/passwd` права тоже в порядке? на хочте используется нормальная unix-аутентификация (ни каких заморочек с ldap или чем-то ещё)? и на всякий случай, команду выполняешь от root'а?

Comment: Да, выполняю с root.

Comment: selinux? getfacl?

Answer (score 1):

```
lsattr /etc/shadow
```

Должно быть так:

```
-------------e-- /etc/shadow
```

Если там стоит атрибут `i` (а скорее всего так и есть), то его нужно снять:

```
chattr -i /etc/shadow
```